# Latex: How to cite a chapter before creating it?

Tags: overleaf

In the beginning of my text, I want to provide an outline of the text and link the corresponding chapters. If i do it this way:

```
\chapter{Intro}
First I will do X, and then in chapter \ref{methods} I will do Y.
...

\chapter{Methods}\label{methods}
...
```

I get the error (which makes sense):
You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled.

**Is there any workaround for this?**

Comment: This should work as it is. Possibly there is another error somewhere else in your document that prevents this part from working correctly. In Overleaf errors are shown in a red square next to the Recompile button. Try to solve those first and hopefully the referencing problem will be solved automatically.

Comment: you can forward reference with `\ref`, please provide an example that shows the issue, not just a fragment that can no be tested,

Comment: You would have to compile the document twice.

Comment: The solution was to simply recompile.. Thanks